# How to find the coordinates under a basis when variables are involved

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how to use row operations when trying to find coordinates of a vector under a basis when both are involving numbers. Simply create an augmented matrix and row reduce. But how do I go about finding the coordinates of the vector ($2x+1+ \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^2}{2}$) under the  basis B = ($x,x^2+x, 3-2x,x^3$)

I already have the solution, can someone please explain the steps to arrive there?

Comment: Write all of these vectors as $n$-tuples relative the the standard basis $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$, e.g., the first vector would be $(1,2,1/2,1/3)$, then do what you always do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the vector as a combination of the base we have:

$$2x+1+ \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^2}{2}=a(x)+b(x^2+x)+c(3-2x)+d(x^3)$$
$$2x+1+ \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^2}{2}=dx^3+bx^2+(a+b-2c)x+3c$$

and using polynomial identity we get:

$$d=1/3$$
$$b=1/2$$
$$a+b-2c=2$$
$$3c=1$$

so

$$a=13/6$$
$$b=1/2$$
$$c=1/3$$
$$d=1/3$$

Comment: thank you. I am guessing you cant apply this method for a vector t  under the basis (1, 1+t, 1+t+t^2), right? you just have to guess it?

Comment: Why not? If you apply the same idea you will get $t=-1(1)+1(1+t)+0(1+t+t^2)$

Comment: I know the answer but I dont see how you get there by writing t = a(1) +b(1+t) +c(1+t+t^2), t = (a+b+c)1 + (b+c)(t) + (c)t^2 .. b= 1-c?

Comment: Same idea: $t=a(1)+b(1+t)+c(1+t+t^2)$ then using polynomial identity $a+b+c=0$, $b+c=1$ and $c=0$ what give us $a=-1,b=1,c=0$. Is that clear?

Comment: no I think I need to take a look at polynomial identities again. Thanks.

Comment: Roughly speaking, two polynomials are identical if they assume the same value for every $x$ taken. That implies they have the same coefficients. But I suggest you take a look in some book for further detail.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I also found the method I was looking for which is to write each vector in the basis as a column vector with 1 representing each degree variable. so the basis would be a matrix with the column vectors:  [0,1,0,0], [0,1,1,0],[3,-2,0,0],[0,0,0,1] and I would form an augmented matrix with the vector [1,2,1/2,1/3] at the end and then row reduce in the calculator to get the coordinates.

Comment: Very good job Tatiana! If you need any other help.

Answer (score 1):

you must solve the equation
$$2x+1+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}=ax+b(x^2+x)+c(3-2x)+dx^3$$ with the unknown variables $$a,b,c,d$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$2x+\color{green}{1}+ \color{red}{\frac{x^3}{3}} + \color{blue}{\frac{x^2}{2}}=\color{red}{\frac 13 }x^3+\color{blue}{\frac 12}(x^2+x)+\color{green}{\frac 13}(3-2x)+ax.$$ So you only need to determine $a.$

Can you see from where come the coefficients in color?